# Java Regex validation for list of numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm a newbie in java regex. i am seeking for advise for this series of number checking :

Number, must be >= 10 digits, user is not allowed to input as follows:

```
"0000000000","1111111111","2222222222","3333333333","4444444444",
"5555555555","6666666666","7777777777","8888888888","9999999999",
"1234567890","00000000000","11111111111","22222222222","33333333333",
"44444444444","55555555555","66666666666","77777777777","88888888888",
"99999999999"
```

currently my regex pattern is something like this

```
^(?=\\d{8,11}$)(?:(.)\\1*)$
```

this validates all numbers in the series except the `1234567890`. any advise is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it valid `0123456789`?

Comment: yes.. if other number than in the list is valid.

Comment: I think you want something as simple as `^(?!(\\d)\\1+$|1234567890$)\\d{10,}$`. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/iQ6jT8/3)

Comment: yes @HamZa i tested it and it works as i expected. thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
^(?!(\d)\1+\b|1234567890)\d{10,}$
```

See what matches and fails in **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC5uK2/2)**.

To validate in Java, with `matches` we don't need the anchors:

```
if (subjectString.matches("(?!(\\d)\\1+\\b|1234567890)\\d{10,}")) {
    // It matched!
  } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The negative lookahead `(?!(\d)\1+\b|1234567890)` asserts that what follows is not...
- `(\d)\1+\b` one digit (captured to Group 1), follows by repetitions of what was matched by Group 1, then a word boundary
- OR `|`
- `1234567890`
- `\d{10,}` matches ten or more digits

Comment: FYI Added regex demo and explanation. :)

Comment: I think you need to add `$` or `\\b` after `1234567890` :)

Comment: My assumption was that he doesn't want `1234567890` at all at the start of the string, e.g., `1234567890555` should fail, but if not, then you're right we need to add a boundary. :)

Comment: @HamZa You and I know that the real problem is if he gets back and says "I also don't want `2345678901`, `9876543210` etc... Problematic for regex unless we want to build a big DENY list.

Answer (score 0):

> Number, must be >= 10 digits, user is not allowed to input as follows.

You can use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method to check for any match.

Try below regex that checks for possible inputs as suggested by you. add more as per your need.

```
1234567890|(\d)\1{9}
```

Here is [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY4hQ0/3)

Pattern explanation:

```
  1234567890               '1234567890'
 |                        OR
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d                       digits (0-9)
  )                        end of \1
  \1{9}                    what was matched by capture \1 (9 times)
```

Sample code:

```
String regex ="1234567890|(\\d)\\1{9}";

System.out.println("0000000000".matches(regex)); // true
System.out.println("1234567890".matches(regex)); // true
System.out.println("1111111111".matches(regex)); // true
```